# Postback with TinyMCE editor in ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tinymce

i wrote this piece of code to use **TinyMCE** (javascript "richtext" editor) on a ASP page. The ASP page itself contains a textbox called "**art_content**", that generates a ClientID like "**ctl00_hold_selectionblock_art_content**".

One problem i had was to make a "safe" code that is stored by my aplication, and loaded back to HTML when i goes to the client, then it return to it's "safe" mode before submiting (or postback) to prevent the HTML check error on server side.

My Javascript seems to work properly, but i get the error anyway. It looks like it's not working, although the function is triggering.

Help!

```
tinymce.init
(
  {
    selector:'#ctl00_hold_selectionblock_art_content',
    plugins:
      ['table link image textcolor pagebreak code visualblocks charmap'],
    toolbar:
      'bold,italic,underline'
  }
);
function SafeCms(text,encode)
{
  if(encode)
  {
    text=text.replaceAll('<','{{');
    text=text.replaceAll('>','}}');
  }
  else
  {
    text=text.replaceAll('{{','<');
    text=text.replaceAll('}}','>');
  }
  return text;
}
$(document).ready
(
  function()
  {
$('#ctl00_hold_selectionblock_art_content').val(SafeCms($('#ctl00_hold_selectionblock_art_content').val(),false));
    $("form").submit
    (
      function()
      {
        tinymce.triggerSave();
        $('#ctl00_hold_selectionblock_art_content').val(SafeCms($('#ctl00_hold_selectionblock_art_content').val(),true));
      }
    );
  }
);
```

UPDATE: Error presented by server side (page)

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$hold$selectionblock$art_content="<p>ab<em>acac</em>ac...").

CallStack:
[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): Um valor possivelmente perigoso Request.Form foi detectado no cliente (ctl00$hold$selectionblock$art_content="<p>ab<em>acac</em>ac...").]
  System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String s, String valueName, String collectionName) +8818818
  System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, String collectionName) +111
  System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +129
  System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() +8818919
  System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) +97
  System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +63
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6785
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +242
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +80
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
  ASP.content_quality_knownledges_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Users\Sammuel\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a3cdd555\dbee70c6\App_Web_e_7yzdu3.2.cs:0
  System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
  System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Comment: What is "the error"? Which line causes it?

Comment: i'll update on my question: it's the "HTTP VALIDATION ERROR" from ASP net, because the interior of the <input> that renders the TextBox contains HTML code

Comment: no one else? hehehe

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [this article](http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2012/05/21/asp-net-4-0-tinymce-and-ldquoa-potentially-dangerous-request.aspx), you can remove the offending HTML characters from the editor content in the `SaveContent` event. If necessary, you can restore them in the `BeforeSetContent` event.

For TinyMCE 4, you can use this code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#ctl00_hold_selectionblock_art_content',
    plugins: ['table link image textcolor pagebreak code visualblocks charmap'],
    toolbar: 'bold,italic,underline',
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on("SaveContent", function (e) {
            e.content = SafeCms(e.content, true);
        });
        editor.on('BeforeSetContent', function (e) {
            e.content = SafeCms(e.content, false);
        });
    }
});

function SafeCms(text, encode) {
    if (encode) {
        return text.replace(/</g, '{{').replace(/>/g, '}}');
    }
    else {
        return text.replace(/{{/g, '<').replace(/}}/g, '>');
    }
}
```

I use `replace` with a regular expression in `SafeCms` instead of `replaceAll` (which does not exist by default in Javascript).

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, you could avoid the mangled `ctl00_hold_selectionblock_art_content` ID with one of these two methods: (1) by setting `ClientIDMode="Static"` for the TextBox and using `selector: '#art_content'`, or (2) with the binding expression syntax `selector: '#<%= art_content.ClientID %>'`.

Comment: yes i know, i posted the code with the ID resolved for example porpuses, it's actually a custom control that i made that writes the javascript code by it self on "render" method

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, in your `web.config` Add:

```
<system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

If you are on .net 4.0 make sure you add this in your `web.config`

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the idea is not to do that.
see that my javascript should replace the HTML in the textarea, prior to the submit so that command (validateRequest=false) would not be needed. i wrote that entire function with the purpose of making the content "safe" to travel.

Comment: What a very very bad practice to disable request validation for **all** pages. Better to disable it only at the page you want `<%@ Page validateRequest="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to manually replace characters, you might always end-up with special cases that you didn't think about and ASP.NET blocks because of security issue.

The best option in my opinion is to encode the content then decode it server side.

I copy my TinyMCE content to an invisible textbox (so user does't end-up seeing an encoded content in his HTML editor)

```js
function encodeContent(copyToId, htmlContent) {
    var encodedHtml = encodeURIComponent(htmlContent);
    $('#' + copyToId).val(encodedHtml);
}
```

Then on server side I just get the content of this textbox and decode it

```cs
var decodedHtml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(this.TextBoxNewContent.Text);
```

I don't know how you initialize your TinyMCE but I personally wrap it in a JS function that I register for calling in the `Page_PreRender` method. In real I've many more parameters, here is a simplified code:

```cs
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var script = "createHtmlEditor('"
       + this.tinyMceEditor.ClientID + "','"
       + this.TextBoxNewContent.ClientID + "');";

    var scriptId = "createHtmlEditor_" + this.tinyMceEditor.ClientID;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), scriptId, script, true);
}
```

`encodeURIComponent` is a native JavaScript function and `HttpUtility` static class is located in `System.Web` namespace

NOTE: when I say "invisible" textbox I'm talking about CSS invisible. Because in ASP.NET `Visibility="false"` will result of your HTML element not created!

Comment: i liked your suggestion too, although the answer from ConnorsFan worked better to my needs